# Geometric transformation that sends a circle to a cycloid

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-transformation, cycloid

Is there a one to one function from the plane to itself (geometric transformation) that sends a circle to its cycloid (i.e. obtained by letting the circle roll over the x-axis)?
If so, can you suggest one?
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest the obvious one: point $r(\theta-\sin\theta,1-\cos\theta)$ on the cycloid is the image of point $r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ on the circle.

Comment: @Aretino : your comment is a true answer...